# WatchConnectivity throwing NSFileReadNoSuchFileError

Tags: ios, watchos, watchconnectivity

We are using WatchConnectivity `transferUserInfo` for sending data between watchOS app and it's companion iPhone app.

Usually we see plenty of errors like:

```
2022-03-02 14:33:26.662926+0100 MSMS[713:229136] [WC] -[WCFileStorage enumerateIncomingUserInfosWithBlock:] could not load user info data at path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DA4E0038-9643-445F-A6DC-8AACB1B1CBEE/Documents/Inbox/com.apple.watchconnectivity/727EC644-8532-4E41-BDB4-2F9D43D5F015/UserInfo/4084BC8F-C0BA-4A8B-911F-2E6254EE102C/userinfo-transfer-object-data due to NSFileReadNoSuchFileError -> ENOENT
```

It seems like phone is trying to access some UserInfo that is not present anymore. Is there some way how to overcome this issue? Or better said, does someone know what is root cause of this issue?